# allow event listener access to variable outside of its function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {

  public function Main():void {
    getOne()
  }

    function getOne():void {
      var varOne:Boolean = false;

      stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dunClicked);
    }

    function dunClicked(e:Event):void {
      if(!varOne) trace("Nope...");
    }
}
```

Now... I know if I put varOne within the Class it will be treated as a sort of 'global variable' (please correct me if I'm wrong...) I was wondering if there's another way for the EventListener to see the value of varOne?

Comment: Declaring 'varOne' as a member of the Main class is the right thing to do. It's not going to be global, it's going to be a property of this class instance. Technically you'll access it by writing 'this.varOne' which can be also written as just 'varOne' like you want to.

Comment: @Philippe, if this is the correct method, please post it as an answer and I will gladly change what I've selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring 'varOne' as a member of the Main class is the best thing to do. Creating a closure (inner function) definitely works too, but not a very good practice because you can't remove an event listener defined using such an anonymous function.

It's not going to be "global", but a property of this class instance, which you should technically access by writing 'this.varOne' (and 'this.getOne()', 'this.dunClicked'...) but in AS3/Java/etc. you can just write 'varOne'.

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {

   private var varOne:Boolean; // defaults to false;

   public function Main():void {
      getOne()
   }

   function getOne():void {
      stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dunClicked);
   }

   function dunClicked(e:Event):void {
      if (!varOne) trace("Nope...");
      // if (!this.varOne) trace("Nope..."); // this is equivalent
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the listener inside the function, so it will become a closure and will have access to local functions vars.

```
function getOne():void {
  var varOne:Boolean = false;

  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dunClicked);

  function dunClicked(e:Event):void {
     if(!varOne) trace("Nope...");
  }
}
```

Comment: i feel super dumb... i didn't know I could nest functions like that... and I've been doing this for a month now =/. Thanks Vita.

Comment: Actually, I'd not suggest using much of this approach because the code readability and supportability will suffer. Just use class vars and regular methods

Comment: This is a **very** poor practice. You limit the scope of the handler and you also have to deal with memory issues (every time getOne() runs, dunClicked() is created and stored in memory. So you do this for 100 objects, it's now created 100 times rather than just once). Basic programming standard practice: **never** nest functions and **never** define functions inline.

Comment: please don't do this.  function closures are ghetto.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 I didn't even think about that... I definitely want to do it 'right' and it seems that this is not the way to go.

Comment: @The Downvoter, this IS a valid answer. Although it's not a method that's suggested, it still resolves the issue in the question. Have mercy on his soul =P